# How to add multiple bind events in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, bind

I need your advice about my jQuery multiple bind. I want to add 2 binds, 1 for #button_sign_in and 1 for #button_sign_up

Here is the code for #button_sign_in :

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#button_sign_in').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

and here is the code for #button_sign_up

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#button_sign_up').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

I tried using that code, but just `#button_sign_in` with enter key worked. `#button_sign_up` didn't work.

Comment: you want to submit button_sign_up and button_sign_in form when hit enter into any control, right??

Comment: Is there a reason not to call both `trigger` method in the same handler?

Comment: @HiteshSiddhapura absolutely yes...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
//give input class to all your form control
$('.input','#button_sign_in').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
   $('form#button_sign_in').submit();
  }
});
```

and follow same for sign up form